# Java Spring email testing with GreenMail

Tags: java, spring, email, greenmail

I am implementing tests for a service which sends a lot of emails.
As a testing tool I selected GreenMail.

I'm doing like

```
@Rule
public GreenMailRule mail = new GreenMailRule(ServerSetupTest.SMTP);

@Autowired
MailService mailService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mail.setUser("recipient1@email.com", "recipient1@email.com", "password");
    mail.setUser("recipient2@email.com", "recipient2@email.com", "password").create();
    mail.setUser("sender@email.com", "sender@email.com", "p").create();
    mail.start();
}

@Test
public void test() {
  // sends mail from sender@email.com to recipient1 and recipient2 using cc
  mailService.send();
  mail.setUser("recipient1@email.com", "password");
  assertEquals(1, mail.getReceivedMessages().length);
}
```

However, I got 2 messages - for both recipients. I think that the reason is smtp based for posting not reading. However if use POP3, I receive no messages at all.

So how can I get messages for specific user?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot. It is s simple server for testing it doesn't provide mailboxes etc. you can only test if the mail got send not if it got dispatched correctly.

Comment: See the [javadoc](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/javadocs/com/icegreen/greenmail/util/Retriever.html). You would need a `Retriever` for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum great thanks! Exactly what I needed